# Deep neural network gives a constant value as output

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression

I have implemented a neural network from scratch. I have taken random values as both input and output. When I use a single layer( with sigmoid activation) the network performs well. But when I increase the number of layers( No matter which activation I use), The network outputs a constant value.

I have attached the link to the full code and output for single layer and and a network with 2 hidden layers.

HyperParameter (relu,sigmoid,derRelu and derSigmoid are functions)

```
alpha= 0.01 #learning rate
m=10 #number of examples in training set
numberOfLayers=2 #including input and output layer
activations=[None,relu,sigmoid]
derActivations=[None,derRelu,derSigmoid]
neurons=[10,5,1]
numberOfIterations=1000
```

Initialization of parameters:

```
parameters=[]
parameters.append({})

for i in range(1,numberOfLayers): 
    param={}
    param["W"]  =np.random.randn(neurons[i],neurons[i-1])*0.01
    param["b"]  =np.zeros((neurons[i],1))
    parameters.append(param)
```

These are some of the functions

```
def calculateZ(A,W,b):
Z=np.dot(W,A)+b
return Z

def derL(Y,A):
derL=np.true_divide(1-Y,1-A)-np.true_divide(Y,A)
return derL

def derW(dZ,A):
dW=np.dot(dZ,np.transpose(A))/m;
return dW

def derB(dZ):
db=np.sum(dZ,axis=1,keepdims=True)/m;
return db

def derZ(dW,dZ,Z,derActi):
dZNew=np.multiply(np.dot(np.transpose(dW),dZ),derActi(Z))
return dZNew

def forwardPropagation(layer):
    W=parameters[layer]["W"]    #current layer
    b=parameters[layer]["b"]    #current layer
    A=parameters[layer-1]["A"]  #previous layer

    Z=calculateZ(A,W,b)
    parameters[layer]["Z"]=Z    #current layer


    A=activations[layer](Z)
    parameters[layer]["A"]=A

def backwardPropagation(layer):
    Z=parameters[layer]["Z"]    #current layer

    if(layer==numberOfLayers-1):
        A=parameters[layer]["A"]
        dL=derL(Y,A)
        dZ=np.multiply(dL,derActivations[layer](Z))
    else:
        dZ=parameters[layer+1]["dZ"]  #next layer
        dW=parameters[layer+1]["dW"]  #next layer    
        dZ=derZ(dW,dZ,Z,derActivations[layer])  #current layer

    parameters[layer]["dZ"]=dZ
    A=parameters[layer-1]["A"]  #previous layer

    dW=derW(dZ,A)               #current layer
    parameters[layer]["dW"]=dW
    db=derB(dZ)               #current layer
    parameters[layer]["db"]=db
```

Training

```
Y=np.random.randn(1,m)
Y=np.where(Y<0,0,1)

# genrating random input to test the code
parameters[0]["A"]=np.random.randn(neurons[0],m)
costs=[]


for i in range(numberOfIterations):
    for layer in range(1,numberOfLayers):
        forwardPropagation(layer)

    
    A=parameters[numberOfLayers-1]["A"]
    l=calculateLoss(Y,A)
    costs.append(l[0][0])

    for layer in range(numberOfLayers-1,0,-1):
        backwardPropagation(layer)

    for layer in range(1,numberOfLayers): 
        updateParameters(layer)
```

[Code](https://github.com/hemant239/DeepNeuralNetwork)

[output with 0 hidden layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r8Br.png)

[output with 2 hidden layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RYTH.png)

I am unable to find the problem.

Comment: So, you've trained it to learn that there is no correlation between input and output (just given it random values), and now the network just outputs an average because it cannot guess the correct output from the input?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt are you saying that it gives a constant value because it is unable to find any co relation between input and output?? If this is the reason why does it not output average/constant value for single layer??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The external code is huge, please post the relevant portions of your code in the question itself, that would help you get more accurate answers. Also, you could start debugging by printing the values of the intermediate layers of the network, and inspecting the gradient values.

Comment: @AravindG. Thank you for your advice, I have included the relevant parts of the code in the post. I tried checking the weights of gradient values, The values are very small almost close to zero, hence the input for sigmoid is a matrix of numbers very close to zero, and the hence only the bias is having an impact on the output. How can I overcome this?